# UNIX colored find output

Tags: unix, colors, find

I know how to color the output of grep, ls (in 256 colors!), prompt and tail. But what would really enhance productivity of a heavy find user like me would be colored find output.

Does such a thing exist? Some web searching yields no promising results for me. It doesn't help that 'find' is such a generic word :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know find doesn't have this built in.  For situations like these I like to use grc (check out https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/grc.1.html).  Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks Madan. That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

grc would suit fancy coloring but simple highlighting can be done with grep. The trick is an extra `-e ^` which matches an empty bit of each line.

```
$ ls
dull.txt  interesting.txt  really_interesting.txt
$ find * -printf '%a %p\n' | grep --color=auto -e ^ -e "[a-z_]*interesting"
Wed Feb  8 17:01:49.0685605700 2012 dull.txt
Wed Feb  8 17:01:49.0686582300 2012 interesting.txt
Wed Feb  8 17:01:49.0688535400 2012 really_interesting.txt
```

Shame about color in Markdown. I've used **bold** above where I have red in my console.

There are plenty of alternatives to the `--color=auto` I've used in my grep example.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the output of find to grep and then play with the colors as needed:

```
find * -iname *Test* -exec ls --color=auto -d {} \; | grep -i Test
```

You can also create an alias like below:

```
myfind() { find * -iname "*$1*" -exec ls --color=auto -d {} \; | grep -i $1 ; }
```

Comment: The basic idea works nicely, I'm tempted to change the accepted answer to this. The only thing is - it doesn't seem to play nicely with pipes, not even `find -exec ls --color=always {} \;  |  head`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

There's a new tool written in Rust that markets itself as `A simple, fast and user-friendly alternative to 'find'`:

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

[image]

I personally haven't had a good experience with it, it breaks a lot of unix-friendly (line-oriented, unix philosophy tenets) functionality that my scripts and pipelines need. And doesn't have some of the features of `find`.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me very well

```
find SEARCH_PATH -name "SEARCH_KEY" | grep --color=auto SEARCH_KEY
```

For example, if you want to **search for the word** "apple" **everywhere**, **starting from the current** directory:

```
find . -name "apple" | grep --color=auto apple
```